# Is it possible to import OSM data from inside psql?

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, psql, dockerfile

I am working on this Bash Script for Dockerfile:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

gosu postgres postgres --single -jE <<-EOL
  CREATE USER "$OSM_USER";
EOL

gosu postgres postgres --single -jE <<-EOL
  CREATE DATABASE "$OSM_DB";
EOL

gosu postgres postgres --single -jE <<-EOL
  GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "$OSM_DB" TO "$OSM_USER";
EOL

# Postgis extension cannot be created in single user mode.
# So we will do it the kludge way by starting the server,
# updating the DB, then shutting down the server so the
# rest of the docker-postgres init scripts can finish.

gosu postgres pg_ctl -w start
gosu postgres psql "$OSM_DB" <<-EOL
  CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
  CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
  ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO "$OSM_USER";
  ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO "$OSM_USER";
EOL
gosu postgres pg_ctl stop
```

i wan to add two import commands after ALTER TABLE:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 -W "latin1" post_pl.shp post_pl  > post_pl.sql
psql -h 172.17.0.2 -U postgres -d gis -f post_pl.sql

osm2pgsql -H 172.17.0.2  -U postgres -d gis --hstore -s -S `./osm_stylesheet ./hessen-latest.osm.pbf`
```

My question is, can it work? Can we import data when we inside psql? And if yes, how can i do it?

TNX

Andrey Ramnikov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just include it into the here-document, using `\i` (you probably need to double the backslash) Assuming your `post_pl.sql` is in the current directory (otherwise specify the full pathname)

```
gosu postgres pg_ctl -w start
gosu postgres psql "$OSM_DB" <<-EOL
  CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
  CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
  ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO "$OSM_USER";
  ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO "$OSM_USER";
  \\connect gis -- Assuming a different DB is needed here ...
  \\i post_pl.sql
EOL
gosu postgres pg_ctl stop
```

---

I am assuming here that `shp2pgsql` does not need the database. `osm2pgsql` which does need the database could be placed right after the `EOL`, just before the `pg_ctl stop`.

Comment: In my Dockerfile i put this ADD commands: RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
**ADD ./osm_stylesheet /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/osm_stylesheet
ADD ./post_pl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/post_pl.sql
ADD ./run.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.sh** but i get an error that .sql file is not there.

Comment: It probably assumes the .sql file to be in a different directory. (or there is a permission- or userid-problem) Try specifying the full pathname. Or create evething you need in /tmp/ )